# jquery optimal method of selecting in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im writing a function that gathers the inputs from a form. But there are many ways to select the inputs. I have looked around and cant find a specific answer based on the methods below.

Is it possible to add multiple selections to a find() (incase i needed to gather input and dropdowns) like you can in a jquery selector?

Which would be the most optimal and why?

Any other alternatives?

**jQuery**

```
//method 1: Id selector
var formId = $('.modal.fade.in').find('form').attr('id');

$('#' +formId+ ' input').each(function(input)
{
     //gather values
}

//method 2: Object and find
var form = $('.modal.fade.in').find('form');

$(form).find('input').each(function(input)
{
     //gather values
}
```

Comment: `form.find('input')` as you are already have the reference to form element

Comment: @Satpal - You saying 'method 2' is most optimal?

Comment: Better you give class to all inputs, including dropdowns, textareas etc. then use that class to select all inputs one shot.

Comment: You can further improve method 2 as I have shown

Comment: @HarryBomrah - Thanks for suggestion, will try it out, probs best way to select multiple elements! Still thou which is optimal method for single selection?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a bigger selector:

```
$('#' +formId+ ' input, #' + formId + ' select').each(function(element)
{
 //gather values from inputs and selects
}
```

Comment: Nice, although is it not possible with `find(input,select)` .Is there a reason you are proposing a selector method over a find method?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
var v = {};
$('#' +formId).find('select, input, textarea'). each(function (){

var tmp;

if($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox' || $(this).attr('radio') == 'checkbox')
{
   tmp = $(this).is(':checked')?1:0;
}elseif($(this).attr('type') == 'submit'){
   return;
}else{
   tmp = $(this).val();
}

v[$(this).attr('id')] = tmp;

});
```